# User has one profile, admin can make many

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-models

I'm building an application with 2 types of users `admin` and `student`. The user model has an attribute `role` with either `admin` or `student`. `users` have one profile but an `admin` should be able to create many profiles.

I can't quite figure out how to model the `profile` model to allow `admin` to create many but `student` to create only one.

What I can do is check whether a student has a profile and remove the create a profile link from their view but I'm sure there is a better way.

other information - using devise for authentication and have added a role attribute to distinguish students(who will be the users) and admin(Me)

Answer (score 0):

```
has_many :profiles, conditions => {:role => :admin}
has_many :profile, conditions => {:role => :student}
```

Comment: You mean `has_one :profile, conditions => { :role => :student }`?

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a base user account then have them interact with different tables based on foreign keys that describe the type of account. For an "airbnb" style user account. A user can have listings as a host or make reservations as a guest:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listings
  has_many :reservations
end

class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  #has a foreign key guest_id
  belongs_to :guest, :class_name => "User"
end

class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  #has a foreign key host_id
  belongs_to :host, :class_name => "User"  
end
```

Hope that helps! Good luck!